# How to load images from public directory in child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I wanted to load images put under **public** directory in my react repository. It would be loaded automatically if I put all componenents inside *App.js* (default path is set in *index.html*). However I extracted my application to different components which were rendered by the parent component *App.js*. The child component here was *rendermovies.js*. How could I modify the path inside *rendermovies.js*?

Here is my file architecture under the react project:

```
public
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
└── manifest.json

src
├── App.css
├── App.js
├── img
│   └── image.jpg
├── index.css
├── index.js
├── rendermovies.js
```

I tried relative link between **src** and **public** to direct the child component to the **img** directory but it did not work. I solved the loading issue by putting **img** directory under **src**, imported it and used `<Card.Img src={} ./>`

```
import defaultposter from './img/image.jpg';
```

in the `render`, I used the following to load the image

```
<Card.Img variant="top" style={{height: 500}} src={ defaultposter } />
```

Or using this way

```
<Card.Img variant="top" style={{height: 500}} src={require(./img/image.jpg)} />
```

Either ways, they both needed the **img** directory under **src** directory

But I was advised to put images and other media for the application under **public** instead of **src**. Regardless, I am wondering how to do that either. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want put the images under the public folder first download `file-loader` https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader and configure it in your `webpack.config.js` the configuration code is below, to get the images from the public folder to child component which is inside the `src` folder you can use this path `../public/img/`, to load the images, put its names in an `array` or state then pass it to child component, then you can iterate on each of those images names using a method the most common is `map()` then reference it by string interpolation like this `${imageName.jpg}`.

```
 // webpack.config.js
 module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {}
            }]
          },
        ],
      },
    };


 <Card.Img variant="top" style={{height: 500}} src={require(`../public/img/${imageName.jpg}`)} />
```